# ReSharper 9.2 produces warning for nameof with event name

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-6.0, resharper-9.2

According to the C# specification this is valid code, and it compiles and runs.

```
var myObj = new MyClass();
var x = nameof(myObj.SomeEvent);
Console.Write(x); // Prints 'SomeEvent'
```

where SomeEvent is:

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
```

But ReSharper produces the warning:

"The event SomeEvent can only appear on the lefthand side of += or -="

I can't find a way to suppress this in Options > Inspection Severity. Is it a bug in ReSharper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-447313). It's fixed in version 10.